# How to link external .cpp or .c file in Freeswitch Module ? What changes needed to done in Auto generated Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, linker, freeswitch

I am new with Freeswitch...
Working on a freeswitch module (mod_test.c),It has Makefile and it works on make and make install..(fine upto this)
Now I have test.h and test.cpp with printSay() function
How to link this test file so that I can call printSay() in my freeswitch module (mod_test.c)

Comment: Or suggest any reference for creating Freeswitch Module which includes above linking scenario

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I have tried "Working with multiple source files" this part from this link https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Creating+New+Modules and problem encountered as "Undefined symbol: printSay()**

Comment: Please post a [mre] with full code and the exact error message